# QT: Why there is no sound?

Tags: qt

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QMediaPlayer voix;
    voix.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/matr/Documents/porque.mp3"));
    voix.setVolume(100);
    voix.play();
}
```

The program builds well with no error, but when i click the button, I hear nothing. I don't understand because the file exists... I checked... I looked in the official documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html#playing-compressed-audio but it doesn't work.....

Comment: What happens when you try to display a messagebox? Make shure your code is realy executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voix is a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of on_pushButton_3_clicked and thus gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You hear no sound because the media player is destroyed at the end of the function. You will have to make the media a member of some longer living object.